# Is the subset $\{P\in C[0,1]: P \text{ is polynomial and} P(0)=P'(0)=0 \}$ dense in $L^1[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the subset $\{P\in C[0,1]: P \text{ is polynomial and} P(0)=P'(0)=0 \}$ dense in $L^1[0,1]$?

We know that for any $f\in L^1[0,1]$ and small enough $\epsilon$, there exists $g\in C_c[0,1]$ , $supp(g)\subseteq [0,1]$ st $||f-g||_1 <\epsilon.$  For continuous $g$ above, we know $g(0)=0$, then there is a polynomial $P$  st  $P(0)=0$, and $||g-p||_\infty <\epsilon$. So the set   $\{P\in C[0,1]: P \text{ is polynomial and} P(0)=0 \}$ is dense in $L^1[0,1]$.

But if we strengthen it a little, we constrain that  the first derivative at $0$ of polynomial  is also $0$, can we get the same result?

Comment: You mean that $\{P \in C[0,1]: P \text{ is polynomial and } P(0)=0\}$ is not dense in $L^1[0,1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f\in C[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and fix $\epsilon>0$. Let $F$ be an even extension of $f$ to $[-1,1]$. Since $F$ is even one can find an even polynomial $w$ (in particular $w'(0)=0$) such that $\sup|F-w|<\epsilon$. Then for $P=w-w(0)$ one has $||f-P||_1\leq\sup|f-P|\leq\sup|f-w|+|w(0)-f(0)|+|f(0)|\leq 2\epsilon$.